# Share variables between index.html and app.js [node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

```
//index.html
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var mySampleRate = audioCtx.sampleRate;

//app.js
var fileWriter = new wav.FileWriter(n + '.wav', {
    channels: 1,
    sampleRate: mySampleRate,

    bitDepth: 16
  });
```

I want to share de mySampleRate [value] of index.html with the node.js serve. How can I do this?

Comment: First thought is an XHR object. What do you intend to do with it on the server?

Comment: You need to define share. Where does this value originate?

Comment: mySampleRate is a number defined by AudioContext (48000Hz). Could change between browsers. I would like to have this process automatic. If the "sampleRate:" is diferent of audioCtx.sampleRate, the process will fail.

Comment: At what point and how does `app.js` get executed? How does it related to `index.html`?

Comment: app.js is a server wich receive audio streaming from a client. I want the audio recording has the same sample rate of AudioContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to create a service method in your node server.

[Express](http://expressjs.com/) is a popular framework, simplifying this process.

```
var app = require( "express" )(),
    bodyParser = require( "body-parser" );

app.use( bodyParser.json() );

app.post( "/rate", function( req, res ) {
    console.log( req.body.rate );
} );
```

And on the client, the browser provides an API for making HTTP requests to the server through an object called XMLHttpRequest, but you could go for something like [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/), for a better API and more consistent implementation throughout browsers.

It should look something like this:

```
var audioCtx = new AudioContext(),
    mySampleRate = audioCtx.sampleRate;

request
    .post( "/rate" )
    .send( { rate: mySampleRate } )
    .end( function( err, res ){
        if ( res.ok ) {
            console.log( "yey" );
        } else {
            console.log( "ney..." + res.text );
        }
    } );
```